# XPATH Query in JRXML

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <pages>
    <page>
        <firstname>X</firstname>
        <lastname>Y</lastname>
    </page>
    <page>
        <firstname>Z</firstname>
        <lastname>V</lastname>
    </page>
    <page>
        <firstname>B</firstname>
        <lastname>S</lastname>
    </page>
    </pages>
```

I want to calculate the number of times page tag is appearing in my XML. 
This information I want to pass it to the subreport which is included in my main report. 
The main report has access to the XML file. 
How can I do this ?

Something like

```
<queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[pages/page]]>
</queryString>
```

I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The XPath expression that counts `page` elements is `count(//page)`. Have you tried it ?

Comment: If I use the following code : 

    <variable name="pageCount" class="java.lang.Object" resetType="None" incrementType="Report">
  <variableExpression><![CDATA[count(//page)]]>      </variableExpression>
    </variable>

Then I get the following exception : 

The method count() is undefined for the type my.jrxml JRXML Problem